# Statement verification - Stable and unstable manifold theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, stability-in-odes

> Let $\dot{X} = f(X)$ have hyperbolic fixed point $\overline{X}$ and linearisation $\dot{X} = Df(\overline{X})X$. Then there exists a stable manifold $W^s_{\overline{X}}$ of dimension $d_s$ and an unstable manifold $W^u_{\overline{X}}$ of dimension $d_u$, $\color{red}{\text{containing }\overline{X} \text{ and tangent to } \overline{X}+E^s, \text{ respectively} \overline{X} + E^u \text{ at } \overline{X}.}$

I'm struggling to understand the english of the part in red... are we saying that $W^s_\overline{X}$ is a manifold containing $\overline{X}$ and is tangent to $\overline{X} + E^s$ at $\overline{X}$, and $W^u_\overline{X}$ is a manifold containing $\overline{X}$ and is tangent to $\overline{X} + E^u$ at $\overline{X}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means.

(I think it's a rather obtuse and needlessly confusing way to write it.)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. And agreed - there are some less confusing ways to make the statement more compact.